# Some LAN trickery

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lan, subnet

New apartment. Two Ethernet sockets in walls. One is connected directly to PC (`device A`). The other is connected to a Netys Wi-Fi travel router (`device B`). Laptop (`device C`) is connected to `device B` wirelessly. Sketch below.

[image]

All three devices have access to the internet. In the network created by `device B`, `nmap` shows that `device C` has local address `192.168.1.3` and its default gateway, `device B`, has address `192.168.1.254`. `Device A` has local address `10.0.1.28` and a `nmap` scan shows `device B` as `10.0.1.22`, although with no open ports. I can ping `device A` from `device C`, however, I cannot do the opposite. Can you please tell me what settings should be applied to appropriate devices in order to ping `device C` from `device A`, or even better, to access a specific port of `device A`, for example, 9999?

I have no clue where the wall sockets go. I'm also bad at networking :>

Comment: I think the first thing you want is a router in one of the sockets, separating you from the rest of the building's apparently open network, with everything connected to that… or ask about how the existing network is supposed to work.

Comment: @Tetsujin True, that would be a good solution, but I currently only posess the mini travel router, which has no ethernet output :(

Comment: So the mini router is on the same subnet as device A, but then handing out its own DHCP, making a new network. That's messy - but it's also a matter of concern because of the lack of security isolation from the rest of the building's network. I've never had to use any shared networking like that, but I would inherently distrust it - or its other users - even if that meant I had to double-NAT to escape it.

Comment: Decent routers are usually not too expensive - that is the way to go so that you are separate from the building system.

Comment: @Tetsujin So if I understand correctly, without messing with whatever connects devices A and B, there is no way to access the device-B-subnet from device A? I wouldn't mind if someone else from the wall-socket network had access to the entirety of device-B subnet or the specific port of device C.

Comment: You could use a broader subnet mask, but that's a bit like leaving your front door wide open because the doorbell's broken. You really want to isolate yourself from the rest of the building, not invite it to more of your devices, open-house.

Comment: This behavior seems to appear because NAT is configured on the router. You can either disable NAT in order to route the packet in a classical way, or you can configure Port Forwarding to redirect specific flow from outside to inside.

Comment: You need to know how the building is configured to do what you want. Otherwise it is clutching at straws.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario is not entirely clear but it looks like this:

1. Your wall sockets are connected to a switch and an Internet uplink.
2. Likely, the switch and private addressing is shared across apartments.
3. Your "Device B" travel router uses NAT between wired WAN and wireless LAN. Likely, NAT cannot be disabled.

Conclusions:

- from 1+2: you'll need a router/firewall to protect your equipment from neighbor hacking
- from 3: you can connect from wireless to wired devices but not vice versa without the implications of port forwarding or exposed host - that router might not be practical for your purpose

Suggestions:

If your travel router doesn't provide wired access, get a decent router with wired and wireless LAN connectivity. Connect all your devices to the router's LAN side. Do not connect anything but the router's WAN port to the wall socket.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion good sir, but I'd really like if `device A` had access to `device B`'s subnet without the additional router, if that's at all possible

Comment: The problem is that you *are* using a (travel) router that you don't want *between* your devices. If it doesn't provide the the functionality that you seem to need - wired and wireless LAN, so you can put it *in front of all your devices*, then you do need another router.

Comment: I hoped that the thing in front of all my devices is the "switch and an Internet uplink" as you suggested. That must definitely be the device which allows `device C` to ping `device A`, no? All I'm asking for is the reverse direction.

Comment: I was trying to point out that the reverse direction is (only) blocked by the travel router that you connected in between. You'd need to set it to bridged or access-point mode, if possible. But then you'd be missing a firewall - which shouldn't only be an option but a requirement.